# Animate click toggle

Tags: jquery

I animate a div when I click (click toggle in the example).I want to animate to the initial position when I click again. (I try with a variable and an if, it does not work. Perhaps there is another easier way? or there is any mistake?)

Please check your answer here:http://jsfiddle.net/uXVxH/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="logo"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#logo {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:-40px;left: 5%;
    width:70px; height:80px;
    background:blue;
    cursor:pointer; 
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function(){
    /* CLICK simple
    $("#logo").click(function() {
        $("#logo").animate({bottom: "0"}, 1200) 
    });
    */

    /*click toggle ?*/
    var hidden = true;
    $("#logo").click(function() {
      if (hidden) {
        $("#logo").animate({bottom: "0"}, 1200);
      } else {
        $("#logo").animate({bottom: "-40"}, 1200);
      }
      state = !hidden;
    });

})
```

Comment: why can't to make the value of hidden as false inside if(hidden) loop.it should work then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is working but you did a little mistake change `state` for `hidden` variable.

```
var hidden = true;
$("#logo").click(function() {
  if (hidden) {
    $("#logo").animate({bottom: "0"}, 1200);
  } else {
    $("#logo").animate({bottom: "-40"}, 1200);
  }
  hidden = !hidden;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var hidden = true;
$("#logo").click(function () {
    var bottom = hidden ? "0" : "-40";
    $(this).stop().animate({bottom: bottom}, 1200);
    hidden = !hidden;
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/uXVxH/6/)

Comment: As it stands, you need a `.stop()` there or toggle the `hidden` variable in the complete callback

Comment: This works!. I have never seen a var like yours with an "?" Can you explain, please?

Comment: @Nrc `condition ? expr1 : expr2` is a **Conditional Operator**. [More details here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**css**

```
#logo {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:-40px;left: 5%;
    width:70px; height:80px;
    background:blue;
    cursor:pointer;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.long {
    bottom: 0 !important;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

**js**

```
$(function(){
    $("#logo").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('long');
    });
});
```

[JS fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/uXVxH/7/)

Comment: This is a good solution. But this css3 does not work in IE Explorer 9 and before. So it needs a solution for this case, and it adds more problems to the case.

Comment: True, the animation wont work in IE9 and below but the performance will be better. I heard microsoft is developing a new javascript engine much like googles. This wont fix it for IE8 and below but hopefully for IE9+, if what I read about microsofts new js engine is correct ofcourse.